# CakePHP how to add data from another field of a related model

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

This is one of my first applications out of tutorials so I don't know how to express my issue well.

Well I have these 2 tables:

> `User ( id, code )`
>
> `Hours ( id, user_id, created)`

I want to know how I can add an entry to the `Hours` table using the `user_code`.

I tried to grab the data of the `User` table with the `code` value and then `findBy` and pass for the `patchEntity` but it did not work.

Comment: Could you include the code for the solution you have currently?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a whole lot of information to work with, but I'll give it a go.

> I want to know how I can add an entry to the Hours table using the
>   user_code

You mention using patchEntity, so that's updating information that's already there. Assuming user_code is the 'code' column you're talking about there, first find the user by his code:

```
$users_tbl = TableRegistry::get('Users');
// find the user
$user = $users_tbl->findByCode($user_code)->first();

if ($user) {
    // replace '$this->request->data() with whatever patch data you wanted
    $users_tbl->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data(), [
        'associated' => ['Hours']
    ]

    if ($users_tbl->save($user)) {
        // success!
    } else {
        // error!
    }
} else {
    // error!
}
```

**It will also depend on how you have the data you passed in** (where my '$this->request->data() is, or whatever your array might be) - it needs to match the right column names and be in the correct format listed [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-request-data-into-entities).

However, this is updating the data. Just adding the data, you can load the hours table and add a new entry with the user_id acquired from the user search:

```
$hours_tbl = TableRegistry::get('Hours');
$hours = $hours_tbl->newEntity([
    'user_id' => $user->id // $user populated from same method earlier
]);
/* assumed 'id' was autoincrementing and 'created' was populated
   through Timestamp behavior */

if ($hours_tbl->save($hours)) {
    // yay!
} else {
    // boo
}
```